# Maximal open coverings without finite subcoverings and the Axiom of Choice.

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, compactness, axiom-of-choice

In my first attempt to prove that the [Ultrafilter Lemma implies Alexander subbase theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963068/ultrafilter-lemma-and-alexander-subbase-theorem), I tried to prove that the Ultrafilter Lemma could be used to show that if $X$ is not compact, then there exists a maximal open cover for $X$ with no finite subcovers. After failing at it, I posted the question linked above, where I learnt an alternative way to do so.

However, this make me wonder about the different equivalences (in ZF) of the statement "*every non compact space has a maximal open cover without finite subcovers*".

It may be a bit silly, but I cannot figure it out if the above statement is equivalent to the Axiom of Choice or any of its restrictions.

So, I would appreciate any references or comments concerning this.