# Is there anything between the Axiom of Choice and the Ultrafilter Lemma?

Tags: general-topology, set-theory, axiom-of-choice

It is well known that the Axiom of Choice (AC) implies the Ultrafilter Lemma (UF), and also that this implication is not reversible.

I was wondering if there exists a statement (S) strictly between them, in the following sense:

> AC $\Rightarrow (S)\Rightarrow$ UF and UF $\not\Rightarrow (S)\not\Rightarrow$ AC, both in ZF.

What motivates this question is the fact that the statement "every open cover (of a topological space $X$) without finite subcovers is contained in a maximal open cover without finite subcovers" ($\dagger$) is enough to prove Alexander's Subbase Theorem (AST), and AST is equivalent to UF.

Since I don't know how to prove neither [UF $\Rightarrow (\dagger)$ nor $(\dagger)\Rightarrow$ AC](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1971790/maximal-open-coverings-without-finite-subcoverings-and-the-axiom-of-choice), I started to wonder if there exists a statement S as described above.

Comment: MC means "The Axiom of Multiple Choice", which unfortunately have two completely orthogonal meanings, one from algebraic and constructive set theory; another from the old-school choice-related research. It is in fact true that in ZF, MC implies AC.

Comment: I guess I made a poor choice of abbreviation.

Comment: Well, sometimes you just don't have any choice... :P

Comment: @Asaf: And sometimes it just depends.

Comment: @Brian: Well, that depends on your previous choices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course. There are plenty!

For one, the Ultrafilter Lemma does not even prove the axiom of countable choice. Therefore $\sf UF+AC_\kappa$ is a strictly in between $\sf UF$ and $\sf AC$, for any $\kappa$. Therefore also $\sf UF+DC_\kappa$ is another intermediate statement.

Comment: Well, I actually had something else to add to this answer, but I forgot it while I was typing this part in. Maybe tomorrow I'll remember it.

Comment: Both the answers are obviously right, but I was wondering of a statement that is not "obviously related to UF", in some reasonable sense. It would be against the rules to add this to my question now?

Comment: Well, I don't see who $\sf AC_\kappa$ is related to the Ultrafilter Lemma.

Comment: AC$_\kappa$ is not related, but $UF+AC_\kappa$ is, because it is explicitly part of $UF+AC_\kappa$.

Comment: Does "Banach-Alaoglu+..." work for you? I could add that as an option.

Comment: As for the edit, I'd rather that you think *through* before you post this edit. I know, it's hard, because you can never know when your question is going to have a trivial answer. I don't mind improvements to the question after I post an answer, but I do rather have them final, and not incremental where each time someone gives you a "trivial answer" and you "improve". So maybe take a day to think about it, then come back and see what's what.

Comment: "Banach-Alaoglu+..." I see what you did there :) Anyway, if nothing "less trivial" appear, I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 2):

Sure - let $\varphi$ be any sentence independent of $ZF+UL+\neg AC$ (say, "There is no uncountable set of reals *not* in bijection with all of $\mathbb{R}$" - the *weak continuum hypothesis*). Then let $S$ be the sentence $$AC\mbox{ }\vee \mbox{ }(UL\mbox{ }\wedge\mbox{ } \varphi).$$ We clearly have $AC$ implies $S$ over ZF, and this implication is strict since $ZF+UL+\neg AC+\varphi$ is consistent. On the other hand, clearly $S$ implies $UL$, and this is strict, since $ZF+UL+\neg\varphi$ is consistent.

---

More generally, given any theory $T$ which is "nice" (here, I mean that Goedel's theorems apply to it) and sentences $\varphi,\psi$ such that $T\vdash \varphi\implies\psi$ strictly, we can find a $\theta$ such that $T\vdash\varphi\implies\theta$ and $\theta\implies\psi$, both strictly.